# Localhost or phpMyAdmin not found on server: How to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I followed installation instruction for `PHP`, `MySQL` and `PHPMyAdmin`. But when I tried to access `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`, I got this error:

> "Not Found The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this
>   server.".

Then I tried to access just the `localhost`, still I got same error.
How can i fix this problem?

I'm using windows 7 (if this problem has something to do with that)

Comment: i already found out the answer, i set a virtual host for localhost that points to htdocs directory.

Comment: Did you read my last comment: if you find an answer, post it as such, and then accept it as correct. Do the same with your older questions. Please follow up on your questions. This is not a dump-and-leave site, the purpose is to collect meaningfull questions-and-answers not only for your but for everyone's finding pleasure.

Comment: i wanted to, but i cannot since site would keep  telling me that i do not have enough reputation to answer my own question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't enough information to be able to give you a reasonable answer.

First check that your Apache is running. Goto your start menu and type services.msc into the text field.

Fairly high towards the top of the screen you will see ApacheX.X

See what the status of the service is. Try double-clicking on the Apache service and pressing Start if the service isn't running. If it has troubles starting you will get a message telling you the service couldn't be started.

Answer (score 20):

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. Insert: `include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` at the bottom of file.
3. Restart apache2: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: it's the perfect solution :) Thank you

Comment: how can it be the perfect solution if you are using windows 7 ?

Comment: Not sure what it is doing, not sure why it was not mentioned in install docs that I was following, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to delete cookies from your browser

press (ctrl + shift + delete) then

time range to clear : Everything

check -> Cookies   then  clear now

done.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished installing xampp 1.8.2 on WinXP XP2 machine and got same error show up on my Firefox 24.0 browser:

> xampp Not Found The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this
>   server.

I solved this problem by changing the proxy of my firefox browser, go to menu tools-Option find tab Network, click button settings. Fill the text box below No Proxy for with localhost.

In my case then it looklike:

```
192.168.1.0/24, localhost
```

Then press Ok, then Ok again.

Try now typing localhost/xampp then it should show Welcome to XAMPP for Windows!

Note: to change proxy for other browser may differ, check your browser help about how to change proxy.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this problem and i've come across an easier solution:

left click on the wamp tray icon
apache>
apache modules>
check the 'rewrite module'

bingo!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is the port conflict for apache server, by default is must be using port 80. You can goto apache configuration file, http.conf and change the port to a different one like: Listen 0.0.0.0:10021
This solved my issue.
If using wamp, you can right click on wamp -> apache -> Use port other than 80, give a port number. Restart all wamp services.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are not able to access localhost** :
One possible reason might be is your apache server is not started. Go to start menu of your computer and search services, open it, find Apache, start the program.(Considering all the configuration of PHP and Apache has done correctly)

**If you are not able to access localhost/phpmyadmin** : 
First of all, add phpmyadmin folder to your working directory. Download it from https://www.phpmyadmin.net and unzip it. Add the folder to your working directory and change the name to phpmyadmin. Now you can access localhost/phpmyadmin. You will see a login page of PhpMyAdmin application. If you are seeing file directories instead of the login page, then go to your apache server's httpd.conf(apache/conf/httpd.conf) file. Edit it and change the index.html of DirectoryIndex to index.php

```
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It also could be because you have changed the directory name, where the phpMyAdmin server sits. make sure the directory/folder name is correct and matches with the locations you used for Localhost to set up.

Also, make sure you have set up [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) server.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin/

this will help to solve the problem with this xampp
if port 80 not work change to 81

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).