# localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/ not found

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I am working on mac with sierra. I have recently installed `apache`, `php`, `mysql` and `phpadmin`. I followed this instruction: https://medium.com/@JohnFoderaro/how-to-set-up-apache-in-macos-sierra-10-12-bca5a5dfffba#.jraxx6f9f  to instal `apache` `php` and to `configur virtual hosts` and this one:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_6g_5S_bVo&t=183s to instal `mysql` and `phpadmin`.

I put my website (html + php) on apache server, all data is stored in `/Library/Sites/foo/`, I can access it via `localhost` and everything works fine.
I have my `phpmyadmin` folder in `Library/WebServer/Documents/`.

After starting mysql and visiting `localhost/phpmyadmin/` or `localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/` or `localhost/phpmyadmin/config/` I am still getting page 404 Not Found.

I have visited many website with similar cases but I can not work it out.

[localhost/phpmyadmin giving page not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772413/localhost-phpmyadmin-giving-page-not-found-error),
[Localhost or phpMyAdmin not found on server: How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868790/localhost-or-phpmyadmin-not-found-on-server-how-to-fix)

In my case `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is empty and adding `"Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf"` isn't working, moreover adding it to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` gives error. I have read that it might by coused because apache server is working and it is impossible to use `phpadmin` and `apache` on the same time on the same place is it true? After stopping apache phpadmin doen't work as well. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you to get through this.

After Configuring apache you need to follow these steps to get connect with local MySQL.

1. Download the "Mac OS X 10.12 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive" - **dmg version** from **https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html** and install the mysql in your mac machine. At end of the installation root password will be generated. kindly copy that password into notes or other files
2. In terminal follow these steps (PURE OPTIONAL)

   - "**cd /usr/local/mysql/bin**" click enter button
   - "**sudo ./mysql -u root -p**" click enter and terminal will ask for 
     password and you need to copy paste the MySQL ROOT password which i 
     mentioned the step 1 and enter.
   - now you will be into mysql and if you want to change the ROOT 
     password then enter this command in terminal "**Alter user 
     'root'@'localhost' identified by 'your new password which you like 
     to change';**" enter and exit from terminal
3. Download phpmyadmin from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ and extract the phpmyadmin file and rename it as **phpMyAdmin**into your WebServer/Documents folder **( /Library/WebServer/Documents/)**
4. Go to Terminal and enter the following command

   - **cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/** and click enter
   - **cd phpMyAdmin** and click enter
   - **sudo mkdir config** and click enter
   - **sudo chmod o+x config** and click enter
5. Go to Browser URL and enter the following **localhost/phpmyadmin/setup** and server set up page will be open and follow the below steps

   - Click on **New Server** button then navigate to authentication tab 
     and enter the **ROOT PASSWORD** & click apply button
   - At bottom of overview page you can find Download button and click 
     that and **config.inc.php** file will be downloaded
   - copy paste the **config.inc.php** file inside your **phpMyAdmin** 
     folder
6. Go to your browser url then enter **localhost/phpmyadmin/** and enter with your credentials into database

Comment: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have solved it. It was because I didn't create a virtual host and hostname for phpmyadmin.
This is how I made it:

1.Use `sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to create virtual host for phpmyadmin I tried:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/piotrek/Sites/phpmyadmin"
ServerName phpmyadmin.localhost
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin-access_log" common 
</VirtualHost>`

2. Go to `sudo nano /etc/hosts` to create hostname entries. I tried:

`127.0.0.1 phpmyadmin.localhost`

3. Restart apache `sudo apachectl restart`
4. Put `phpmyadmin` file into Sites

Everything works fine, I can create new database and work with it :)

Comment: Doing this basically allows you to view phpmyadmin when going to `phpmyadmin.localhost` on your browser, and not `localhost/phpmyadmin`, correct?